# Node.js multer: can't upload same file twice

Tags: multer

I have a node.js web app and I use multer to upload files (stl 3D models). When I try to upload some file it works, but when I try second time the same file It's doing nothing, but other files works and also 1.file_1 2.file_2 3.file_1 works.
I can't find out why it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions to try?

my code: 
index.js

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploaded/user_files')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    last_upload_file_name = makeid(10) + "_" + file.originalname;
    last_upload_file_name_formal = file.originalname;
    cb(null, last_upload_file_name)
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post('/api/upload', upload.any(), (req, res) => {

    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    upload_username = res.locals.user.username;

    console.log(">> record");
    console.log(">> user: " + res.locals.user.username);
    console.log(">> file: " + last_upload_file_name);

    // mongodb record (filename | user | date)

    res.end(last_upload_file_name);

});
```

HTML

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/upload" method="post">
    <label class="input_file_label_style button" id="file_input_slicer_submit_label" >choose a file</label>
</form>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: update I use also js to validate .stl code here ``

Answer (score 0):

Solved I found out that it's because I had stuck file in the input file.
I used this:

```
$("#file").replaceWith($("#file").val('').clone(true));
```